# Changing position in game is making problems

Tags: game-maker-studio-1.4

I tried to create table game with character and wanna to change position of my character through dice.

All points, where I wanna to get are saved in array `global.array_points[1]` to `[20]`: `global.array_points[1]] = point_1;`

When dice got number from 1 to 6  in step function of my character is:

```cpp
if(character.x != global.array_points[global.new_complete_position].x &&
character.y != global.array_points[global.new_complete_position].y)
{
   global.position_character += 1;

   x = global.array_points[global.position_character].x;
   y = global.array_points[global.position_character].y;
}
```

Sometimes my code is working perfect, but sometimes, my game still works, but character does not to know change position.

Do you know, how to solve this problem please?

Comment: sorry I was mistake, code to changing positions is following:

Comment: global.position_character += 1;

   x = global.array_points[global.position_character].x;
   y = global.array_points[global.position_character].y;